# Android error - unable to load image

Tags: android

I want to share an image using any applicable app such as instagram.
However, the following code returns "unable to load image"

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (curJoke.getImgUrl() != null) {
            ParseFile file = curJoke.getParseFile(ParseConstants.IMAGE_COLUMN);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getUrl()));
            sendIntent.setType("image/*");
        }

        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "share an joke");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions. Even though you want to share an image, you're really asking about an error, so name your question accordingly. Also, for Java (and Android), giving the full stack trace is very helpful. Finally, don't forget to read the help, tour and faq.

Comment: thanks for your help . I am approve your edit